# Corona SDK Android back key navigation

Tags: android, sdk, navigation, coronasdk, back

I'm having problems with the Android Back key. The Corona forums haven't helped me. No matter what scene I'm in, the back button will only bring me back to the main menu, rather than the previous scene like it should.

A map of my app...

Menu > Menu2 > Tutorials > Tutorial1

Tutorials should go back to Menu2, Tutorial1 should go back to Tutorials, but both go back to Menu.

I have this function below in all of my scenes with their respective "changeScene"'s to go back to the previous screen; but as I mentioned, ALL bring me back to the main menu.

```
    local function moveBack()

     Runtime:removeEventListener("key", onKeyEvent)

     display.remove(allObjects);allObjects=nil

     director:changeScene("previousScene", "crossfade")

end

local function onKeyEvent( event )
        local returnValue = true

        if (event.phase=="up" and event.keyName=="back") then
                timer.performWithDelay(100,moveBack,1)
        end

        return returnValue
end
Runtime:addEventListener( "key", onKeyEvent )
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you probably should not be removing the event handler for key.  If you do, it won't respond to future back button presses.

Secondly, director:changeScene("previousScene", "crossfade") will try to goto a scene in a file called previousScene.lua.  I don't think this is what you want to do.

You probably should setup a "history" table where you can record the next scene to go back to and in the moveBack function, go to the last scene in the list and then remove the entry from the table.  When you enter the scene you would add the scene to go back to into the table at the end.